# How can we configure the event hub, so that it collects/consumes events from a specific role inside a cloud service?

Tags: azure

I am testing a Cloud service(classic) that has multiple roles running under it. I need to collect specific error events from some of these roles. I am wondering if there is a way for the event hub to consume application error events from these roles?

Comment: Hi Mr-Mozy, could you please add more details and context to your question so it's easier to answer? Right now it's a little bit too open

Comment: For the event hub to be able to consume anything a process needs to send data to it. Do you already have any of such process available?